# how to update column with row number in group by result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join, window-functions

Sample Data:

```
id  |  room_id  |  seat_num
----------------------------------
1   |   1      |  null
2   |   1      |  null
3   |   2      |  null
4   |   2      |  null
```

Desire Data:

```
id  |  room_id  |  seat_num
----------------------------------
1   |   1      |  1
2   |   1      |  2
3   |   2      |  1
4   |   2      |  2
```

how to write a sql to update the room seat number to serial num in MySQL 5.7? the room's seat is from 2-20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option uses the update/join syntax. In MySQL 5.7, where window functions are not available, you can emulate `row_number()` with a correlated subquery (which is somehow safer than user variables):

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, 
        (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.room_id = t.room_id and t1.id <= t.id) rn
    from mytable t
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.seat_num = t1.rn
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d3bfb55d505ff06f124769d71fd9082c)**:

```
id | room_id | seat_num
:- | ------: | :-------
1  |       1 | 1       
2  |       1 | 2       
3  |       2 | 1       
4  |       2 | 2
```

Comment: it is very slow in the db that have 70000+ rows. @GMB

Comment: @Dolphin: make sure that you have an index on `room_id, id`, that could help. Bottom line though: if you want efficient ranking functions, the consider upgrading to MySQL 8.0...